# Internet Explorer forces user to log into site with DOMAIN\USERNAME

Tags: 2010, authentication, internet-explorer

I have a public Internet facing site running on SHarePoint 2010 using NTLM authentication. Users using FireFox/Chrome/Safari are able to log into the site using just their username and password. Internet Explorer users, however, are forced to log in with domain\username. If the domain is left out the site will not grant the user access.

I have been instructing users to try to use another browser but most of our user base uses IE. We have two separate domains. Internal users belong to DomainA  and External users are in DomainB. I am not sure why IE is forcing the inclusion of the domain in the username while the others do not. I need users to be able to log in with just username and password only. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks!

Comment: Does this affect all IE users, i.e., those accessing the site from inside the company firewall as well as from outside or is it limited to one group?

Comment: This affects all IE users both internal and external

Comment: In IE, you can't set the intranet site as a Trusted Site?

Answer (score 6):

Try using "\\" before the username when you login to the sharepoint website from client machines.

Comment: I used a single "\" and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I tried one "\" but that did not do it for me but two "\\" did, thanks! IE9 and SP 2013.

Answer (score 3):

A Couple of things you can try:

1. In internet explorer, uncheck the "Enable Integrated Windows
   Authentication" box in the security options page.

   This doesn't actually disable it, it just forces NTLM.  When the
   checkbox is clicked it will try to use Kerberos first, than it is
   supposed to fall back to NTLM (IE7+).
2. I would also suggest loading up fiddler and comparing the
       authentication headers when you use the other browsers with the one
       generated by IE.

Does this happen to both internal (users on same domain as server) and external (trusted domain)?  How are the authentication option in the WebApp configured (IIS settings)?

Comment: This happens for all IE users in both the trusted and the domain the web server exists on. We actually did switch from NTLM to kerberos in order to use forms based authentication. 

The IIS Settings for authentication have both forms based (HTTP 302 login/redirect) and windows(http 401 challenge) authentication enabled. I will run the fiddler trace and make a comparison. THanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, Kerberos and FBA are two different authentication methods, independent of each other.   You may want to try and switch back to NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, but as it turns out our clients are in a different domain than our sharepoint server. When authentication takes place, the client computer implicitly sends your complete authentication information, i.e. your domain\username and password. When the authentication request arrives at the server, it realizes the user doesn't belong the same domain as it does. Consider configuring a trust between your domain for transparent authentication. Greetings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The external users are on DomainB which is the same domain as the Sharepoint server. There is also a one way trust between DomainA and DomainB where DomainB trusts DomainA. ALso, This only happens in internet Explorer. This does not happen in FireFox, Chrome, or Safari

Answer (score 0):

In IIS under the ISS Site -> Authentication -> Windows Authentication

Right click and select Advanced settings.  Under the advanced settings check the box labeled "Enable Kernal-Mode Authentication" and then reset IIS.

Answer (score 0):

When IE (11) prompts for credentials you should be given the option to "remember" them with a "Windows Security" pop-up (in W7 Pro).

We often set "remember" for some of our internal (in**tra**net) sites and you only need to set the \domain\userID once and it should remember it.

All our users laptops are *not part of the internal domain* as they work remotely and access by VPN.

If the wrong domain is shown, such as our laptop "computer name" is the same name as the user's login name. "Windows Security" show that as JaneDoe19\JaneDoe19 or it lists "Domain: JaneDoe19" blow the account field **and** the AD server (whatever maintains the user's authentication info) is NOT part of that domain *you have to specify which domain to use to look for credentials*.

Therefore, if "Windows Security" says JaneDoe19\JaneDoe19 you have to "Use another account" and set it to the correct \domain\userID and then remember it.

Beware though that we have found that after using "remember", when accessing the site with Chrome it seems to "mess" with whatever stores those credentials and IE11 will stop bringing up the "Windows Security" pop-up so then you get "Web page can't be displayed". Looking at the details we see "authentication error (denied, whatever)". Even clearing the remembered credentials with "control userpasswords2" from an elevated command prompt will not necessarily make IE11 pop up the "Windows Security" credential window or if it does authentication may still fail. (Rebooting doesn't help.)

Answer (score -2):

try domain\username and ythen you may get somewhere and also your password

Comment: And that was exactly what OP did not want to do :)

Comment: this is one of the best answers i've seen on this site